# Dynamic prototype based UITableViewCell works weird, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

UITableView's cell is set up in interface builder with dynamic prototype. The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method is used to get cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Then I set the texts in cell, but the textcolor what I set in prototype is not taken into effect (neither from code nor set on prototype in interface builder). And not only the color, but `Right Detail` is set as style in interface builder, but on screen it shows as `Basic` style, so the `detailTextLabel` content is not able to be seen.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ooo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel!.text = "asdf1"
    cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "asdf2"

    return cell
}
```

- "ooo" is set as identifier in interface builder
- table view controller's class correctly in the storyboard
- I haven't register a cell or nib with the table view

Comment: It sounds like you haven't arranged for this table view to get its cells from the storyboard. Did you set the table view controller's class correctly in the storyboard? Did you mistakenly register a cell or nib with the table view?

Comment: I changed and changed back in StoryBoard the Table View Cell Style from Right Detail to sth else and select Right Detail again, and set color / highlighted color again